# loop for valid user input c++

Tags: c++, file-io, ifstream

New to C++ but I have some programming experience...

I'm trying a very basic approach to getting a filename from the user, then opening the file. I'm using some non-standard libraries (Stanford libraries), but I don't think that should affect things.

```
     ifstream in;
while(true){
    string filename="";
    cout << "Enter the name of the file. ";
    getline(cin, filename);
    in.open(filename.c_str());
    if (in.fail()){
        cout << "ERROR opening file. Try again.";
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
     ... more code ...
```

If I enter a valid file name first time, it works fine and moves on. If I enter an invalid file name, I get the error message and it loops around to ask for another file name, but then it treats all subsequent entries as invalid even if the file is valid. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks!

Comment: The input stream would go to error state when you input an invalid data and it will ignore future inputs.Try to clear the stream if u need to use it again for input.But I had cases where the problem persist even after i clear the input stream.

Answer (score 2):

Try calling `in.clear()` after `if (in.fail()){`. This will clear the file status bits so your next call to `fail()` will see the result of the last `open` call (as opposed to seeing last failed `open` status). [From c++ docs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios/clear/):

```
void clear ( iostate state = goodbit );
```

> Set error state flags Sets a new value for the error control state.
>
> All the bits in the control state are replaced by the new ones; The
>   value existing before the call has no effect.
>
> If the function is called with goodbit as argument (which is the
>   default value) all error flags are cleared.

Comment: This is probably the right answer, but pointless unless you explain why. Programming shouldn't be about trial and error. "Hey, if I add `clear` after the condition, it works! Let's do that."